# How to scroll till an element that is inside an i frame

Tags: java, selenium

I need to click some element that is inside an iframe. When page is loaded these elements are not visible and I scroll down to make them visible. I tried as follows:

1. Move to iframe and `switchTo(frame)`
2. `javascript.executeScript(argument[0].scrollIntoView(true), webelement)`

Scrolling is happening only once. When I click first element. I need to scroll down and click the next element (it is a submission form in ui). All elements are in iframe.

Can anyone suggest any idea I'am using java with selenium.

Comment: Please share you code, html in text format and problem/error you get

Comment: Do you mean java*script*?

Comment: You don't have to scroll to click... just find and click the element and Selenium will scroll the page for you.

Comment: without your actual code, it's hard to know what it does, but do you know that you only have to switchTo() once, and all subsequent actions will work within that frame?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", myIWebElement);
```